# Trivial compile time check for no copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

A well-known idiom for making no-copy types is to create a base class

```
struct NoCopy {
   NoCopy(){}
   NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
   NoCopy& operator=(const NoCopy&) = delete;  
};
```

And derive from this, like so

```
struct Foo : NoCopy {
    Foo(){}
};
```

Which will make the following fail to compile

```
Foo f;
Foo f2 = f;
```

But how do I enforce this? Any derived class can do the following

```
struct Foo2 : NoCopy {
    Foo2(){}
    Foo2(const Foo2&){}
};
```

Which is perfectly legal but makes no sense, I have now a type which is both copyable and also not copyable (through its base class).

How do I avoid this?

Comment: [<type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible) header has those checks. You could use the result of the check in `static_assert()` or some sort of SFINAE expression.

Comment: Foo2(const Foo2&) calls NoCopy::NoCopy() unfortunately..

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think this particular situation is likely? Of course the user can write meaningless/ill-formed code. Writing a copy constructor for their class that does not call copy constructors of base classes is an example of that, but even if you somehow prevented that, there are certain levels of malicious/uninformed that you won't be able to counteract. IMO your job is done if you clearly make the base class as uncopyable.

Comment: @MaxLanghof It might be of interest if you are writing code to be used as library

Comment: @arynaq Again (and maybe even especially in that case), if your users are hellbent on shooting themselves in the foot, you can't stop them. If you had a perfectly copyable class (with a default constructor) and they forgot to call its copy constructor in theirs, they'd have the same issue.

Comment: @arynaq Which code?  `NoCopy` or `Foo`?   Because deriving from `Foo` and then not copying it is a valid operation (your copy semantics just consist of not copying `Foo`) if a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is C++. In the world of template meta-programming almost anything is possible. If we make `NoCopy` a CRTP base, we can add static assertions in its destructor.

```
template<class C>
struct NoCopy {
   NoCopy(){}
   NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
   NoCopy& operator=(const NoCopy&) = delete;
   ~NoCopy() noexcept {
       static_assert(std::is_base_of<NoCopy, C>::value, "CRTP not observed");
       static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible<C>::value, "A non-copyable copyable class? Really?");
   }
};
```

Here's your code, adapted for a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/757aac8535f7b712).

That's not without a price though, since now the class is not trivially destructible, and as such neither will be any class that derives from it. Whether or not it's acceptable is up to you.

---

Upon further reflection, if you provide only a single way to intiialize your class, then the default constructor *has* to be referred to and called. So the static assertion can be moved there, and the type is back to being trivially destructible:

```
template<class C>
struct NoCopy {
   NoCopy() noexcept {
       static_assert(std::is_base_of<NoCopy, C>::value, "CRTP not observed");
       static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible<C>::value, "A non-copyable copyable class? Really?");
   }
   NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
   NoCopy& operator=(const NoCopy&) = delete;
};
```

The static assertion fires just the same, as [this live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fe7e8b59137d64a) shows.

Comment: Note that this [can still be defeated](https://godbolt.org/z/Tzml_W). Takes more malicious intent than forgetting a base-class copy constructor, but still.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Anything can be defeated. The point of the exercise is to ward off Murphy. Machiavelli always lurks.

Comment: @liliscent - An immediately derived class cannot have a copy constructor, because then an assertion will fire. That, to me, is the whole point.

Comment: Of course. But it's not particularly unlikely that you forget to change the CRTP parameter if you copy an existing derived class and run into this exact issue. It helps, but as you mentioned it has drawbacks. Whether those are worth guarding against this specific scenario is up to the reader to decide.

Comment: Thanks for the help with warding off Murphy, which often ends up being me!

Comment: It's partly because OP's requirement is so bizarre, deriving from `noncopyable` should be enough for any reasonable use. I thought they were asking a more thorough approach ... Anyway, this answer is interesting +1

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to guard against people accidentally forgetting to call the `NoCopy` copy constructor in their own (forbidden-by-naming) copy constructor, I would suggest this:

```
namespace
{
    struct NotCopyableInitT {};
}    

// You can choose whatever stern words you want here.
NotCopyableInitT initNoCopy() { return {}; }

struct NoCopy {
    explicit NoCopy(NotCopyableInitT){}
    NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
    NoCopy& operator=(const NoCopy&) = delete;  
};
```

If they insist to add copyability where it is forbidden, you force them to spell out their own mistake:

```
struct Foo2 : mylib::NoCopy {
    Foo2() : NoCopy(mylib::initNoCopy()) {}
    // Users have to spell out this line in order to get a copy constructor.
    // That certainly goes beyond being forgetful.
    Foo2(const Foo2&) : NoCopy(mylib::initNoCopy()) {}
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XgcCAg)

For well-behaved users, it's one extra function call in the `NoCopy` constructor (which at least a linter would tell you to call explicitly anyway).

Comment: I like this. In C++17 I'd prefer an inline variable to a function, but otherwise this has a very nice declarative feeling to it.

Comment: A downside is that your derived type is no longer trivially constructible.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply *check* that the types used with your API are not copiable:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace lib {
template<class NoCopy>
inline constexpr bool copiable_v = std::disjunction<
    std::is_copy_constructible<NoCopy>,
    std::is_copy_assignable<NoCopy>
>::value;

template<class NoCopy>
struct CheckNoCopiable
{
    static_assert(
        copiable_v<NoCopy> == false,
        "Type is copy-assignable or copy-constructible."
    );
};
}
```

With that tool, your functions could look like:

```
namespace lib {
template<class NoCopy>
void f(NoCopy&& nc)
{
    CheckNoCopiable<NoCopy>{};

    /* do whatever with nc */
}
}
```

Full program demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed0a8f5576a68554:

```
struct Alice   : lib::NoCopy {}; // nice Alice
struct Bob                   {}; // nice Bob
struct Charlie : lib::NoCopy     // naughty Charly
{
    Charlie()               {};
    Charlie(Charlie const&) {};
    Charlie& operator=(const Charlie&) { return *this; }; 
};

int main()
{
   lib::f(Alice{});
   //lib::f(Bob{});     // error: static assertion failed: Type is copy-assignable or copy-constructible.
   //lib::f(Charlie{}); // error: static assertion failed: Type is copy-assignable or copy-constructible.
}
```

Comment: Oh this is interesting, I didn't know you could call static assert like that